# MUI Autocomplete value clear:- Two autocomplete 2nd autocomplete options is depended on 1st autocomplete value

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, autocomplete

Problem:- Consider Two MUI Autocomplete 1st is Category autocomplete and 2nd is subcategory. On selecting category value from options we get options for subcategory on the basis of value selected  on category.
For example:- category document has name and id and subcategory array. so we have these multiple category and nested subcategory in it.
[category document structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nxkye.png)

Now, when we are selecting value from category options we are getting options for subcategory by filtering out the subcategory array. After that when we are changing category autocomplete value the sub category autocomplete value is not getting changed although options are getting changed real time on the basis of category value.

I tried clearing subcategory value in onChange function of category autocomplete but value in subcategory still remains but in console it is showing undefined.

Comment: Consider adding a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.